# Kafka Schema from a case class with list of struct type fields

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, struct, schema, avro

I am trying to auto generate kafka schema from a case class in scala which has some fields of type struct.

```scala
  def generateKafkaSchema[T: SchemaFor]: Schema = {
    val avroDataConfig: AvroDataConfig = new AvroDataConfig.Builder().`with`("", true).build()
    val avroData: AvroData = new AvroData(avroDataConfig)
    avroData.toConnectSchema(AvroSchema[T])
  }
     }
```

I have

```scala
case class A (name:option[String], age:Option[Int]}

case class B (id:int, details:Option[A])
```

The auto schema generation worked on case class A but on case class B it gives an error:

> Struct schemas do not match.
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Struct schemas do not match.

Does anyone know what is the issue here?